# Relative completeness of first order arithmetic

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, incompleteness

Gödel's incompleteness theorem tells us that the language of first order arithmetic $PA_1$ is strong enough to express a statement about its own consistency, which cannot be proved in $PA_1$.

More generally if we take $PA_n$ to be $n$-th order arithmetic (that is we allow quantification over sets in $\mathcal P^n\mathbb N$), to what extent can we guarantee that if a formula $\phi$ is valid and can be stated in $PA_n$, then it has a proof in $PA_{f(n)}$?

Is there a common terminology for such "relative" completeness results?

Comment: What are your axioms for $PA_n$?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss It's open to interpretation, but I'm essentially thinking of ZF restricted to $n$-th order quantification as described

Comment: @Couchy311 Are you envisioning $PA_k$ as a $k$th-order theory or a first-order theory? (Keep in mind that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is a first-order theory.) If the former, you need to also specify what you mean by "proof."

Comment: @NoahSchweber $PA_k$ is a viewed as a first order theory

Comment: @Couchy311 In that case the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel%27s_completeness_theorem) (also due to Godel :P) applies, as it does to all first-order theories - including $PA_1$, incidentally (the Godel sentence is *not* a logical validity, even granting $PA_1$: it is true in some models of $PA_1$ and false in others).

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're right, thanks, this becomes trivial. Validity is not the right concept for the question I was thinking of. Perhaps I will post a refinement of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) - also due to Godel! - says that this always happens, at least for first-order theories:

> Suppose $T$ is a first-order theory. If $\varphi$ is a sentence true in every model of $T$ then $\varphi$ is provable from $T$, and conversely. Or in symbols, $$T\models\varphi\quad\iff\quad T\vdash\varphi.$$

This does not contradict the *incompleteness theorem*. That result says that $PA_1$ is not a complete theory: there is a sentence (indeed, lots of sentences) $\sigma$ such that $PA_1\not\vdash\sigma$ and $PA_1\not\vdash\neg\sigma$, or equivalently by the completeness theorem $PA_1\not\models\sigma$ and $PA\not\models\neg\sigma$. The term "(in)complete" is being overloaded here:

- A *theory* is complete if it proves or disproves each sentence.
- A *proof system* $P$ is (sound and) complete with respect to an existing semantics if $P$-provability coincides with entailment in the sense of that semantics.